# Accessing javascript variable in embedded ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, variables

I use the following JS code in my view to calculate two variables "user_name" and "user_uid":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f1() {
.
.
.
user_name = "some variable";
user_uid = "another variable";
});
}
</script>
```

I'd like to send the two variables "user_name" and "user_uid" to my controller. I use the following code:

```
<%= link_to "GO!", new_user_path(:userName => user_name, :userUid => user_id), :remote=> true %>
```

My Controller and model work OK. But the two variables are not passed from the JS to the above embedded ruby code. I'd appreciate any pointers on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Biggest mistake is not knowing where code is executed:

- Code inside `<%= ... %>` ([Erb markers](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)) is executed on the server, before clients see any HTML.
- JS is executed on the client, after being sent from a server.

There are a number of options, including creating the JS variable values using Ruby variables–whether that's the *best* option depends. For example:

```js
function f1() {
  var user_name = "<%= escape_javascript(a_ruby_variable) %>";
  // Or, more concisely:
  var user_uid = "<%=j another_ruby_variable %>";
```

The Ruby variable could be initialized in the template, the controller, etc.

Again, whether it *should* be is debatable.

Comment: Thanks Dave! The two variables are created using FB API. They are created in JS. Do I have any other options? Thanks!!

Comment: @user1388066 That's a problem then; you'd need to build the link in a different way, or submit a form, or rewrite the link, or...

Comment: The link itself is working OK. If I set the variable within the link_to, it works fine. The variables are not being set the way I'd like to set them. And I'm not sure if that is even possible since my variables are set in JS. Thanks Dave!

Comment: If your controller MUST access this information then you will have to use an AJAX call. Transmitting to the info to your server, processing it, and returning an appropriate response. However, if you can, its much better to avoid doing this..

Comment: @user1388066 As I said, you need to *build* the link a different way--the link is useless by itself, it needs to be built to actually include the data you need. That's why I'm saying it needs to be built in a different way, because the server side doesn't have access to the client-side JS values.

Comment: Thanks @diedthreetimes!! At this point, I think I have two options: 1. Is what you suggested. 2. Find out if I can accomplish the same thing through the FB API. Thank you!!

Comment: @diedthreetimes Just curious why are you saying: "it is much better to avoid doing this" Thanks!

Comment: I think the only option that I have, given that I want to use FB api, is what @diedthreetimes suggested: "Use an AJAX call. Transmitting the info to your server, processing it, and returning an appropriate response."

Comment: Such a call usually adds unnecessary complexity to the app. In most cases, you should be able to modify the page directly with javascript. When you make an ajax call you have to wait another entire RTT in order for the user's page to fully load. This doesn't seem like a lot, but it adds up quickly. Its best if all information can be transmitted from server to client once, and that information then be manipulated by the client side javascript as necessary for proper presentation. I don't know what specifically you are doing, but usually, the simpler the better.